# Powershell regex doesn't exclude square brackets

Tags: powershell

I have a file in location $Path with this content:

```
[abc]
value = 123

[def]
value = 123

[ghi]
value = 123
```

To get all section names, I tried to use this command:

```
 Get-Content $Path | Select-String "(?<=\[)(.*)(?=\])"
```

And the output is:

```
[abc]
[def]
[ghi]
```

What am I doing wrong, and why do I see square brackets in command output? I checked my regex on regex101, and it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is the whole line in which the match was found. To grab only the matched substring, reference the `Matches` collection attached to each output object:

```
Get-Content $Path | Select-String "(?<=\[)(.*)(?=\])" | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```

---

How would I know? By using the `Get-Member` cmdlet!

```
PS ~> Get-Content $Path | Select-String "(?<=\[)(.*)(?=\])" | Get-Member


   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo

Name         MemberType Definition
----         ---------- ----------
Equals       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode  Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType      Method     type GetType()
RelativePath Method     string RelativePath(string directory)
ToString     Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string directory)
Context      Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfoContext Context {get;set;}
Filename     Property   string Filename {get;}
IgnoreCase   Property   bool IgnoreCase {get;set;}
Line         Property   string Line {get;set;}
LineNumber   Property   int LineNumber {get;set;}
Matches      Property   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[] Matches {get;set;}
Path         Property   string Path {get;set;}
Pattern      Property   string Pattern {get;set;}
```

As we can see here, `Select-String` outputs objects of the type `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`, which has a number of members, including the `Matches` property

Comment: Nice. Note that there's a green-lit proposal - yet to be implemented - to add an `-OnlyMatching` switch to `Select-String`, which would directly output only the matching part of the lines - see [GitHub issue #7712](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7712)